# Is System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState same as Session class? if so how?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

In my code in global ASAX file I see this code:

```
Session("ErrorSource") = lastError.Source
Session("ErrorPATH") = Request.Path.ToString()
```

If I right click on Session and then choose Goto definition I get:

```
Public Default Property Item(ByVal name As String) As Object
     Member of: System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState
```

Above clears why we don't have

Session.Item("ErrorSource") = lastError.Source (because item is the default propery of Session)

What I don't understand where Session class itself is defined?

I expected to have something like SessionState.HttpSessionState("ErrorSource")

Not Session.Item("ErrorSource") .   So where Session is defined?

Comment: `Session` is a member of your System.Web.UI.Page, and that member is an `HttpSessionState` object.

Comment: you are correct:

Public Overridable ReadOnly Property Session() As System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState
     Member of: System.Web.UI.Page

What is wonder is WHY when we click on goto definition of session on VS, we wont get directed to the defintion of Session itself. But to a class that happens to have a propery of type of session.

Comment: Because whatever class you are working in inherits `System.Web.UI.Page`. Since the `Session` object isn't implemented on your class, it takes you to the class that DOES implement it for you (`System.Web.UI.Page`).

Comment: @SNash, it redirects you to the definition of `Item` because that's what you're accessing on that line. I suspect that if you remove the parentheses it would take you to the `Page.Session` property.

Comment: @Mike Corcoran: Why/How you explanation changed into a comment? Put it as an answer and I will Accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Session` is a member of type `HttpSessionState` of the `System.Web.UI.Page` object that the class you are currently developing in looks to be inheriting (it may also inherit `System.Web.UI.UserControl`, these are the two main classes you inherit `Session` from).

When you choose 'go to definition' in Visual Studio, it will find the place where that member is actually defined, even if it isn't defined in the current class (but is instead in a base class or interface)